# Adjusting the Layout of an App on all iOS Devices

Tags: ios, swift

I have created my application on Xcode in iPhone11 pro Max, and I want it to work on all iPhone devices. Is it possible to automatically configure the layout so that it works and displays the screen perfectly on all devices without manually varying the traits for all classes of iOS devices? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, you have to use AutoLayout. You can find a lot of information on the web.

Comment: @Gius I have used auto-layout. But, it changes the orientation for different devices. Especially for smaller devices the objects on the screen are hidden

Comment: So do I have to change the orientation manually for each device? Or is there any other way to do that automatically? Thanks!

Comment: AutoLayout is the most effective and simple method, otherwise you should do it via code. If something is hidden on the small displays it means that you have not applied autolayout well. On youtube there are numerous videos about it. If you have too many elements you can think of using ScrollView too.